# Base64Encode for AWS not matching Amazon Example

Tags: amazon-web-services, groovy

I seem to be failing at the first hurdle in my quest for Amazon S3 Browser-Based Uploads.

Using Amazon's example shown here : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html

Using Groovy/Java, I'm unable to encode the example post policy and produce the same encoding as Amazon.

```
{ "expiration": "2015-12-30T12:00:00.000Z",
  "conditions": [
    {"bucket": "sigv4examplebucket"},
    ["starts-with", "$key", "user/user1/"],
    {"acl": "public-read"},
    {"success_action_redirect": "http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
    {"x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274"},
    {"x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"},
    ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""],

    {"x-amz-credential": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request"},
    {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
    {"x-amz-date": "20151229T000000Z" }
  ]
}
```

I have this defined as a Groovy multi line string:

```
String policy_document = '''
{ "expiration": "2015-12-30T12:00:00.000Z",
  "conditions": [
    {"bucket": "sigv4examplebucket"},
    ["starts-with", "$key", "user/user1/"],
    {"acl": "public-read"},
    {"success_action_redirect": "http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
    {"x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274"},
    {"x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"},
    ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""],

    {"x-amz-credential": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request"},
    {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
    {"x-amz-date": "20151229T000000Z" }
  ]
}
'''
```

I'm then encoding and verifying with an assert which fails.

```
String base64Policy = (new BASE64Encoder()).encode(policy_document.replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("\r", "").getBytes("UTF-8"))
assert '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' == base64Policy
```

**Just to help with readability, when I encode I get :**

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

**But I should be getting :**

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

I'm hoping a fresh set of eyes will point me in the direction.  Many thanks for any advice that can be offered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me in Java. Leave the carriage return and line feeds in place.

```
String policy_document = "{ \"expiration\": \"2015-12-30T12:00:00.000Z\",\n" +
            "  \"conditions\": [\n" +
            "    {\"bucket\": \"sigv4examplebucket\"},\n" +
            "    [\"starts-with\", \"$key\", \"user/user1/\"],\n" +
            "    {\"acl\": \"public-read\"},\n" +
            "    {\"success_action_redirect\": \"http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html\"},\n" +
            "    [\"starts-with\", \"$Content-Type\", \"image/\"],\n" +
            "    {\"x-amz-meta-uuid\": \"14365123651274\"},\n" +
            "    {\"x-amz-server-side-encryption\": \"AES256\"},\n" +
            "    [\"starts-with\", \"$x-amz-meta-tag\", \"\"],\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    {\"x-amz-credential\": \"AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request\"},\n" +
            "    {\"x-amz-algorithm\": \"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\"},\n" +
            "    {\"x-amz-date\": \"20151229T000000Z\" }\n" +
            "  ]\n" +
            "}";
    String base64Policy = (new BASE64Encoder()).encode(policy_document.getBytes());
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm still getting slightly different results.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

The final solution was to add \r\n in that order at the end of each line.

```
String policy_document = "{ \"expiration\": \"2015-12-30T12:00:00.000Z\",\r\n" +
        "  \"conditions\": [\r\n" +
        "    {\"bucket\": \"sigv4examplebucket\"},\r\n" +
        "    [\"starts-with\", \"$key\", \"user/user1/\"],\r\n" +
        "    {\"acl\": \"public-read\"},\r\n" +
        "    {\"success_action_redirect\": \"http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html\"},\r\n" +
        "    [\"starts-with\", \"$Content-Type\", \"image/\"],\r\n" +
        "    {\"x-amz-meta-uuid\": \"14365123651274\"},\r\n" +
        "    {\"x-amz-server-side-encryption\": \"AES256\"},\r\n" +
        "    [\"starts-with\", \"$x-amz-meta-tag\", \"\"],\r\n" +
        "\r\n" +
        "    {\"x-amz-credential\": \"AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request\"},\r\n" +
        "    {\"x-amz-algorithm\": \"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\"},\r\n" +
        "    {\"x-amz-date\": \"20151229T000000Z\" }\r\n" +
        "  ]\r\n" +
        "}";
```

It's unfortunate that it needs to be implemented so rigidly and that using a Groovy multi line string cannot accomplish this to keep the markup cleaner.

Comment: You don't need to end it with windows newlines. That's just the example. You just need the base 64 encoding to match your input.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Tim.  Yes, I think you're right.  I should be able to create the policy using Groovy JSON too.  However, just to verify that I'm doing the next cryptography step correctly, I needed an exact match on this encoding as it serves as an input to the crypto step.

Comment: I'll try and remember to update this question to reflect that once I'm through the entire process.